# how to write a loop query with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have this table

| id | i1 | i2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y001 | x1 | a1 |
| Y001 | x1 | a2 |
| Y001 | a1 | a5 |
| Y001 | a2 | a3 |
| Y001 | a3 | a4 |

The relationship between i1 and i2 is i2 contains i1,so a1 contains x1, a5 contains a1, I want to get the final relationship for all items.

The expected result is

| id | i | i_final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y001 | x1 | a5 |
| Y001 | x1 | a4 |
| Y001 | a1 | a5 |
| Y001 | a2 | a4 |
| Y001 | a3 | a4 |

Comment: If it's possible to have duplicates within `i1` column then what path woul you choose while descending the hierarchy? Suppose there's another row with `i1 = 'x0'` and `i2 = 'x1'`

Comment: What version of oracle you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want a "loop". You want to use a hierarchical query and find the leaves of the hierarchy tree for each root:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT i1 AS i1,
       i2
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR i2 = i1
AND    PRIOR id = id -- Not sure if this is needed as you only have one id value
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, i1, i2) AS
SELECT 'Y001', 'x1', 'a1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y001', 'x1', 'a2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y001', 'a1', 'a5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y001', 'a2', 'a3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y001', 'a3', 'a4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | I1 | I2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y001 | a1 | a5 |
| Y001 | a2 | a4 |
| Y001 | a3 | a4 |
| Y001 | x1 | a5 |
| Y001 | x1 | a4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pR24zXus)